# Adding image textures in texture paint

Tags: texture-painting

There are many tutorials on how to use multiple textures in modeling detail onto the mesh but it seems impossible to find how to paint or stencil paint more than one texture onto a single object.

Is there a way in Blender to import or open multiple image textures and use them one after another on various parts of the same model like you can in other texturing apps such as Sculptris?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: you can change the brush texture and paint on the object as much as you want, maybe show a screenshot of what you're trying to do or what you've achieved so far...

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply.
Often these questions answer themselves as you become more familiar with Blender.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do this is pretty useful to me, so I will share this method here:

First, select the images you want to use and make copies in a new folder, renaming them with whatever tool or program you want to follow a sequence like 'image.001, image.002, etc' so that the same image name is shared and they follow a sequential number.

Load them as a new brush texture or brush mask depending on what you want to use them as.
[image: load new images]
[image: select all images in sequence]

Add a timeline editor to your workspace if not present, and set the end frame number to match the number of images in your image sequence.
[image: set image count to frame count in timeline]

Use the playhead controls or the left/right arrow keys to switch images as you paint.
[image: scrub timeline to switch images]

Another neat trick is that you can press the Play button and paint, your dabs will change texture corresponding to where the play head is on the timeline. This can be used for many effects like randomly mixing wear images or changing scratch marks, or even just imitating Alchemy for idea generation.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.
I appreciate you taking the time to answer my question.
Seems you have a creative way to paint multiple textures on a mesh.
Blender is an amazing tool but still requires a high learning curve to be able to do ordinary tasks done in other apps.
But you can't complain about FREE.

Answer (score 0):

First, create a material for the object with whatever base texture you want (or just a base color).
[image]

Then, in the texture panel, create a new image texture for each texture you want to paint with.

[image]

Finally, in Texture Paint mode, under the brush settings (found in the Properties window under the Active Tools tab), Under Brush Settings -> Texture, select the texture you just created and start painting with it.

[image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you.
Sorry for the late reply.
Very simple to follow instructions.
I was texturing in about five minutes.